# Using the Stack Exchange API to request a user's "flair"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flair, api

First of all, I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask Stack Exchange API questions, but I couldn't find a meta site for the API.

So obviously if you want to create a piece of Stack Exchange "flair," you can go to the area of profile designated to that and you are given some nice examples and some easy copy and paste bits of code like this for example:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/2698266/wold">
<img src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2698266.png" width="208"
height="58" alt="profile for Wold at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and 
enthusiast programmers" title="profile for Wold at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for 
professional and enthusiast programmers"></a>
```

[image: profile for Wold at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

So this bit of code is easy enough to modify, replacing my unique id with another other user's unique id, but I was wondering if a more direct way to request "flair" could be added to the api. I was thinking it might be something  like `/users/{ids}/flair/{preferences}`  where `id` would obviously be the id and `preferences` would be the theme type or a place to specify combined-flair.

Would something like this be possible/reasonable to implement?

**Edit:**  [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/2119/se-flair-html-combined-stack-exchange-site-flair) already exists and is basically exactly what I was looking for. I guess I would just feel more comfortable using a functionality like this that is part of the official Stack Exchange API and would be much less likely to become deprecated for whatever reason.

Comment: Hm, I did rewrite [StackFlair](http://stackapps.com/questions/1567/stackflair-generate-flair-for-your-stack-exchange-associated-accounts-please), but haven't gotten around to hosting it for public use yet.

Comment: SE-Flair produces a richer flair than what Stack Exchange sites produce; it is an alternative to the simpler image-only flair.